# How to document attributes in Kotlin data class?

Tags: java, kotlin, javadoc, kdoc

Where shall I put Javadoc analogy for attributes in KDoc in Kotlin data class?

In other words, how to write in Kotlin KDoc the following Java code Javadoc:

```java
/**
 * Represents a person.
 */
public class Person {
    /**
     * First name. -- where to place this documentation in Kotlin?
     */
    private final String firstName;
    /**
     * Last name. -- where to place this documentation in Kotlin?
     */
    private final String lastName;

    // a lot of boilerplate Java code - getters, equals, hashCode, ...
}
```

In Kotlin it looks like this:

```kotlin
/**
 * Represents a person.
 */
data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String)
```

but where to put the attributes' documentation?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html), you can use the `@property` tag for this:

```
/**
 * Represents a person.
 * @property firstName The first name.
 * @property lastName The last name.
 */
data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String)
```

Alternatively, simply mention the property names in the description of the class, if you don't have much to say about them in the docs:

```
/**
 * Represents a person, with the given [firstName] and [lastName].
 */
data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String)
```

Comment: It's a pity that IntelliJ Idea does *not* generate the skeleton when I type `/**` in front of the class - in a similar way as it *does* for method parameters. It is a lost chance to educate us :)

Comment: It's intentional. See http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#documentation-comments for an explanation why.

Comment: That's a valid point. Please consider enhancing your answer with this information, this *is* educational. I mean that it is intentional and why - you have already touched this reason anyway.